# Change form palette via google scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I need a help. I am using Google App Scripts for creating Google Forms. How I can change form's color/palette?

I tried to find here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/, but nothing found.

Comment: I don't see anything in the documentation to change the forms color.

Comment: Created an issue: http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=6381

Comment: Any update on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the moment you can't, FormApp works with the first version of Forms, so for the moment no templates available programmatically.

Last news on the subject [here](http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.fr/2016/02/new-google-forms-now-default-option.html)

Comment: is this still the case?

Comment: The linked question points to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36762042, which is still open at the time of writing.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue here and found a workaround: create a "Template Form" with the proper theme you want, then you make a copy of it and do your coding to the new copied form.

The problem is, if you want to custom each form with a theme, it would need several template forms, and the code should be able to select the correct template. However, this is not my case. Here is a sample code:

```js
var file = DriveApp.getFileById('your-template-form-id').makeCopy();
var form = FormApp.openById(file.getId());
```

Just make sure you remove the single question that is created within the template form if you're adding questions dinamically, else, add the questions you need.

Comment: Thanks, I will try

Answer (score 0):

Good to note that once you generate a form programmatically, you can then edit it just like a regular form. You get the link to the editable page from `form.getEditUrl()`.