# Change background color of a Google Form using the App Script API

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a way to change the background color of a Google Form programmatically using the App Script API?

Comment: Related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37302543/change-form-palette-via-google-scripts).

Comment: Created an issue: http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=6381

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, there is no way to change the color of a Form via the App Script API.  The only object the supports a `.setTheme(theme)` method is `Site`.

I know, I am sad, too.

Fortunately, once you generate a form programmatically, you can then edit it just like a regular form. You get the link to the editable page from `form.getEditUrl()`.

Any changes you make there will be saved to the form itself. So, maybe you can just tinker around with it a bit at the end and it will look how you need it to.