# Google Form: manipulate DOM element

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a Google Form that, on load, I want to find a specific input box and manipulate - this example, changing the background to red.

This is what I have so far, but it doesn't appear to work. I tried using `console.log` instead to see if it was working but it didn't seem to do anything.

**Current project's triggers**

```
Run: myFunction
Events: From form | On Open
```

**Code**

```
function myFunction() {
  document.querySelectorAll('[aria-label="Job ID"]').setAttribute("style", "background-color: red;");
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean, `on load`? Programmatic changes and scripts only run on the editor view - you cannot alter it run scripts for the respondent view.

Answer (score 1):

Right now it is not possible to style **Google Forms** unless you copy the code and self host it.

See related questions:
[Change background color of a Google Form using the App Script API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39294184/change-background-color-of-a-google-form-using-the-app-script-api)
[Change form palette via google scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37302543/change-form-palette-via-google-scripts)

And issue on google.com:
[Issue: Access to the color palette option in Google Forms](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36762042)

Comment: What I would like to be able to do, for example, is change the input type from text to number using a similar approach. Do you know if this is possible 'natively'? Due to work restrictions, it looks like the only place I have immediate access to is a google sites installation, so perhaps equally restrictive.

Comment: Can you give more information about what you want to achieve? Why do you want to change the input type when loading the form? Why don't you just design the form appropriately before loading it?

Comment: I'm using native Google Forms. They allow you to use validation such as only accepting numbers on the response of 'short answer' but no way to specify input type.

Comment: Yes you can use predefined validation (number, text, length) or custom validation by using regular expressions. Regular expressions use specific patterns to check the input value. E.g. try regular expression matches: ^\d+$ => this specifies your input type to allow only one or more numbers. Or to restrict numbers from 1000 to 2999 use this regex: ^[12][0-9]{3}$ (it means, let the number begin with 1 or 2 and then followed by 3 numbers which can be from 0-9).